# While loop only takes one condition

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

The while loop command only takes one condition or it'll ignore them entirely. The script ends up running the program infinitely.

[image: You can clearly see that the loop doesn't stop even with blue = True]

[image: same thing here]

I've tried running the keyboard condition as a variable.
I've also tried a variable counter (while i < 4) as one of the conditions with the same results.
Switching the conditions and putting them in parenthesis didn't work either.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you understand the logical meaning of `or`?

Comment: Yeah, if one or the other condition is met, the result is true. Why, is that the issue?

Comment: Your `while` loop continues forever because despite the fact that one of the conditions is false, the other one is true.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Should've used the `and` keyword instead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the 2 conditions is true then it keeps on looping.

In order to exit the loop **both** conditions MUST be **false**.
Meaning :

- `blue` must be true
- `q` must be pressed

Don't know `pyautogui` and its `is_pressed()` behaviour. May be you've to keep the finger on the `q` key to satisfy the 2nd condition ?